# Disable Cache for Safari 14.x

Tags: macos, safari

I have seen plenty of posts on how to disable caches for developing on Safari macOS - but they're all for older versions of Safari - and those options no longer seem to exist for Safari 14.x

I can't find it in the Develop menu, I can't find it on the Network tab etc ...

Where is this option?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it, it's a tiny icon on the upper right of the networks tab:

[image]